# Bootstrap align form textfields

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap and am trying to create a simple form with 13 fields. 
I am using inline since I want to display the fields next to each other (Label: Textbox)
It is working fine on mobile device (listed one under the other which is OK) but on PC it does not appear ordered. How can I align the fields in three columns for example to make them look ordered on PC browser. This is my current output: 
http://upupa.byethost10.com/session1.html#

My code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Session Details</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Session Details</h2>
  <p></p>
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Date:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Site">Site:</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="Site" name="Site" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Xaghra</option>
      <option value="2">Option two</option>
      <option value="">Populated by database</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ringer">Ringer:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ringer" placeholder="Ringer">
    </div>

       <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Net Length">Net Length:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Net Length" placeholder="Net Length">
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Net Remarks">Net Remarks:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Net Remarks" placeholder="Net Remarks">
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Tape Lure 1">Tape Lure 1:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tape Lure 1" placeholder="Tape Lure 1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Tape Lure 2">Tape Lure 2:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tape Lure 2" placeholder="Tape Lure 2">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Tape Lure 3">Tape Lure 3:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tape Lure 3" placeholder="Tape Lure 3">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Remarks">Remarks:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Remarks" placeholder="Remarks">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Cloud Cover">Cloud Cover:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cloud Cover" placeholder="Cloud Cover">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Wind Direction">Wind Direction:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Wind Direction" placeholder="Wind Direction">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Wind Strength">Wind Strength:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Wind Strength" placeholder="Wind Strength">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Rain">Rain:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Rain" placeholder="Rain">
    </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

thanks

Comment: Look at the horizontal form instead of inline forms. Then you can create grid columns, and place your form inside there (the labels and fields will still be inline).

Comment: What do you want the form to look like on desktop? How many fields per row, how many rows, etc?

Comment: I only want to sort everything in 3 columns so that they can appear ordered on pc

Comment: Remove form class `class="form-inline"`  http://www.bootply.com/pmJwuFbBSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `input`s that you want grouped together into rows using `<div class="row">` and each `form-group` into columns with (for example) `<div class="col-md-4">`.

I did this for your first set of three inputs here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonmrich/bz59xucp/

Check into the documentation for Bootstrap to see how to use rows and columns effectively.